# incorrect date validation using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im trying to use moment to validate the date input on my form, however for non existent dates such as 30th february instead of saying invalid date it will add the extra day onto the month meaning that it will output `1980-03-01` instead of taking the date as `1980-03-01` and invalidating the date

How can I get it to validate the date correctly?

```
const validateDate = (year, month, day) => {
    let validationMessage;
    const isNotEmpty = year && month && day;
    const date = isNotEmpty && `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
    const toDateFormat = moment(new Date(date)).format(dateFormat);
    const isDateValid = moment(toDateFormat, dateFormat, true).isValid();
    const isYearValid = (year > 1900 && year < new Date().getFullYear());

    if (!isDateValid) {
        validationMessage = `invalid date`;
    }

    return {
        isValid: isDateValid && isYearValid,
        validationMessage,
    };
};

export default {
    validate: validateDate
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const date = moment('2020-02-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
const isValid = date.isValid(); //false

const date = moment('2020-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
const isValid = date.isValid(); //true
```